# how could i make the JFrame content change to corresponding click?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a simple desktop application with java. There is a menu bar, when the user clicks on menu item 1 then the content will change to form A. When a user clicks on menu item 2 then the content will display form B.

How could i achieve this?

**using the same window** and just the content change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sample for you, I just did to refresh my swing knowledge..

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FrmChange extends JFrame{

private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

public FrmChange(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initMenu();
    panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
}

private class MenuAction implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel panel;
    private MenuAction(JPanel pnl) {
        this.panel = pnl;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        changePanel(panel);

    }

}

private void initMenu() {
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
    JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Panel1");
    JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Panel2");
    menubar.add(menu);
    menu.add(menuItem1);
    menu.add(menuItem2);
    setJMenuBar(menubar);
    menuItem1.addActionListener(new MenuAction(panel1));
    menuItem2.addActionListener(new MenuAction(panel2));

}

private void changePanel(JPanel panel) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().doLayout();
    update(getGraphics());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FrmChange frame = new FrmChange();
    frame.setBounds(200, 200, 300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: thank you, Gursel Koca =D even simple for me while rush to finish within few days <3

Comment: anyway, your sample is not working @.@ i spent a day time to combine this into my action, it failed, then i tried to compile this alone...one error - 
Local information is not present, i'm still new in JAVA and could not solve this, may i know where is the problem. please =D

Comment: it just lacks import statements.. except import statements, there is nothing missing.. which ide are u using?

Comment: Thx to Gursel because you finally solved my problem, and to say thx i open a free TFS account for you at my server...check your mail =D

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), or simply remove the displayed panel and add the one you want to display the the frame content pane.

You need to add an `ActionListener` to each menu item in order to trigger the appropriate change ech time a menu item is clicked.

This is really basic Swing functionality. You should read the [Swing Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: Easiest ^^ Thx to JB Nizet =D

Answer (score 4):

```
frame.getContentPane().remove() or removeAll();

frame.getContentPane().add(allTheNewComponents);

frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: dude, may i know how could i make the components ? please...i know nothing about java but need to submit the assignment soon @.@ is it make another new class or method ?